# Postgres 9.1 statistics in pg_stat_database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, statistics

I've been searching for some information about Postgres 9.1 stats which are stored in pg_stat_database - on the web and on IRC. I found SOME information for 9.2 but even that doesn't seem to be accurate. What I'm after is to get proper transaction stats ie commits and rollbacks. Also I've no clue what tup_fetched and tup_returned mean.

I made a few tests on a dummy database. I created a database called `statistics` and one simple table called `films` in it. Inserted a few values into it and here is what I found out:

```
statistics=# select xact_commit, xact_rollback, blks_read, blks_hit,tup_returned, tup_fetched, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted from pg_stat_database where datname='statistics';
 xact_commit | xact_rollback | blks_read | blks_hit | tup_returned | tup_fetched | tup_inserted | tup_updated | tup_deleted 
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------
          94 |             0 |       182 |     3259 |        18345 |        1293 |           27 |           0 |           0
(1 row)

statistics=# INSERT INTO films VALUES ('UA509', 'Bananas', 105, '1971-04-13', 'Comedy', '85 minutes');
INSERT 0 1
statistics=# select xact_commit, xact_rollback, blks_read, blks_hit,tup_returned, tup_fetched, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted from pg_stat_database where datname='statistics';
 xact_commit | xact_rollback | blks_read | blks_hit | tup_returned | tup_fetched | tup_inserted | tup_updated | tup_deleted 
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------
          97 |             1 |       182 |     3261 |        18345 |        1293 |           28 |           0 |           0
(1 row)

statistics=# select * from films;
 code  |  title   | did | date_prod  |  kind  |   len    
-------+----------+-----+------------+--------+----------
 UA502 | Bananas  | 105 | 1971-07-13 | Comedy | 01:22:00
 UA503 | BanaAAas | 106 | 1971-07-13 | Comedy | 01:26:00
 UA504 | BanaAAas | 106 | 1971-07-13 | Comedy | 01:26:00
 UA509 | Bananas  | 105 | 1971-04-13 | Comedy | 01:25:00
(4 rows)

statistics=# select xact_commit, xact_rollback, blks_read, blks_hit,tup_returned, tup_fetched, tup_inserted, tup_updated, tup_deleted from pg_stat_database where datname='statistics';
 xact_commit | xact_rollback | blks_read | blks_hit | tup_returned | tup_fetched | tup_inserted | tup_updated | tup_deleted 
-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------
          99 |             1 |       182 |     3262 |        18349 |        1293 |           28 |           0 |           0
(1 row)
```

What this shows is that `xact_commit` increases by **3** after just one row insert. `tup_inserted` does seem to report correct value.
After simple `SELECT`, `xact_commit` increases by **2** - kind of strange as `SELECT` shouldn't really be increasing `xact_commit` ?
What I'm trying to do is to gather some reasonable data which would give me an idea about how many transactions/s particular Database is doing.
Could any of the gurus shed some light on this ? I take it that `tup_fetched` and `tup_returned` are some really damn random values which only Postgres developers understand :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `tup_fetched` and `tup_returned` are pretty clear. `tup_fetched` is the number of rows "touched" (looked at, fetched, read from disk) by any query. `tup_returned` is the number of rows returned to the client. The number returned is e.g. reduced by a where clause during a seq scan (the seq scan would "fetch" *all* rows, but only "return" e.g. *one*)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `pg_stat_database` is thoroughly described [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW).

As to the increasing `xact_commit`. You might be have `AUTOCOMMIT=on`. PostgreSQL will *always* run all your queries in a transaction. In case `AUTOCOMMIT=on`, `COMMIT` will issued after each statement executed.

In your case you have 2 statements:

- *previous* `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database`;
- your test statement, like `SELECT 1`

You might try the following scenario:

- open 2 sessions, S1 and S2;
- S1: SET autocommit TO off;
- S1: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;
- S1: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;
- S2: SELECT 1;
- S1: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;
- S2: SET autocommit TO off;
- S2: SELECT 1;
- S1: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;

You can continue playing around yourself.